# differences in using equality operator in php

Tags: php

can anybody tell me the difference of using '===' as

```
if (null === $this->getName())
```

and

```
if ($this->getName() === null )
```

if $this->getName is already defined.

thanks in advance

Comment: The variables are switched, and the second one has a space before the close parenthesis.

Comment: The first one is a means simply to get the comparison value visible - helps the developer parse the meaning of the code quickly, which is helpful on longer lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between the two conditionals, however, it is a common practice to place the value you are checking first, so you don't accidentally turn a conditional check into an assignment operation:

```
// Conditional
if ($this->getName() === null )

// Assignment
if ($myName = null )

// Avoids the confusion of either the above
if (null === $this->getName())
```

You can also use the [is_null](https://www.php.net/is_null) PHP function for testing if variables are null.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference as long as you are using `===` or `==`.

Now you might wonder why someone written all their values at left side. This is because we devs tend to forget or have typo writing `==` and we type `=`. This is makes accidental assignment.

```
if($id=13){
  echo "foo";
}
```

Its hard to find the problem in above code. Which should have been written as `$id==13`. Those who writes as `13==$id` doesn't have to deal with the issue becase when they forget a `=` it becomes `13=$id` which is a syntax error. This way such *almost impossible to detect errors* are avoided.

Answer (score 0):

The `===` operator in PHP is symmetric, so those are identical.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, the only notable difference is strictly in the order of writing, enabling an easier following of given tests in some cases.

I also consider PHP evaluating first term first, but this won't be producing any difference since they will both be evaluated anyway.